# org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name userController : Unsatisfied dependency

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I try to connect mysql database to spring boot web service but i got this error and i don't know how to fix it ...

my controller is :

```
    @RestController
    @RequestMapping("/user")
    public class UsersController {

    @Autowired
    UserService userService;

    @RequestMapping("/test")
    @ResponseBody
    String home(){
        return "Hello world";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/users")
    String test(){
        return "TEST ";
    }
}
```

and my Entity is :

```
@Entity
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    private String username;
    private String name;
    private String firstname;
    private String email;
    private String adress;
    private String password;

    // Constructeur pour l'utilisation des JPA
    protected User(){}

    public User(String username, String name, String firstname, String email, String adress, String password) {
        this.username = username;
        this.name = name;
        this.firstname = firstname;
        this.email = email;
        this.adress = adress;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getFirstname() {
        return firstname;
    }

    public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getAdress() {
        return adress;
    }

    public void setAdress(String adress) {
        this.adress = adress;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

My repository file :

```
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Integer>{
    List<User> findUserByName(String name);
    User findUserByUsername(String username);
}
```

My service :

```
@Service
@Component
public class UserService {
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository repoUser;

    public List<User> getUser(String name){
        return repoUser.findUserByName(name);
    }
}
```

EDIT : 
This is my stacktrace :

```
2016-08-05 20:48:39.025  WARN 1849 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'usersController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userService': No qualifying bean of type [services.UserService] found for dependency [services.UserService]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [services.UserService] found for dependency [services.UserService]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
2016-08-05 20:48:39.026  INFO 1849 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2016-08-05 20:48:39.031  INFO 1849 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service Tomcat
2016-08-05 20:48:39.053  INFO 1849 --- [           main] utoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report enable debug logging (start with --debug)


2016-08-05 20:48:39.073 ERROR 1849 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'usersController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userService': No qualifying bean of type [services.UserService] found for dependency [services.UserService]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [services.UserService] found for dependency [services.UserService]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:569) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:349) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:776) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:861) ~[spring-context-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541) ~[spring-context-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:369) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:313) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1185) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1174) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at com.example.JitBackofficeApplication.main(JitBackofficeApplication.java:13) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147) [idea_rt.jar:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [services.UserService] found for dependency [services.UserService]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1406) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1057) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1019) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:566) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    ... 24 common frames omitted
```

My aplication.properties :

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/jitdatabase
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.data.jpa.repositories.enabled=true
```

Here my Application file :

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan("controllers")
public class JitBackofficeApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(JitBackofficeApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

[here theres is my architecture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5TQRI.png)

Anyone have an solution ?

Regards

Comment: Where's the error that you got?

Comment: The error is on usercontroller because i can t autowired userService :/

Comment: What packages are your classes in?

Comment: Not the scope of this question, but, why using `@Service`
`@Component` annotation together?

Comment: UserService is depending of UserRepository. are you sure it is correctly instantiated? normally you have to go to the last exception in a stack trace to get the actual error/ the top ones are ripples of the original issue.

Comment: Share your application-context.xml

Comment: this error is related with configuration.Check you base component scan package also check the dependency mentioned in pom is having same version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `@ComponentScan` annotation is wrong. You only add the controller package as a component source.

You need to add the package that contains both your controllers and Services.

Eg if your package structure is:

> com.mycompany.controllers
>
> com.mycompany.services

Then write com.mycompany into the `@ComponentScan`.

Also you should only use `@Service` on your service classes and not `@Component`.

Comment: What should White un my componentScan ?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help !

Answer (score 0):

I got this problem before，I trace it and found that this is not the error of controller and service but the repository.I got this by the exception stack 'caused by xxx'.Finally I found the reason,I made a mistake when I config the datasource in application.properties,which lead to failure to connect the database.

But your error is incomplete.I think your error is like as mine and I have some question to confirm.

1.Can you show your complete exception stack?

2.Can you show your application.properties?

3.Are you make sure that your database can connect successfully?You can use jdbc to test it.

4.Do you have one datasource or more?More that one datasource will make configuration complex and have more probability to error.

Comment: I edit my question, my database work and i still do not understand why my web service does not work ... I think the problem is about my entity or repository

Comment: Saw your exception stack,I guess it is because the @ComponentScan does not scan your service.Can you show your JitBackofficeApplication class.Or Are you make sure your ComponentScan is configured right?The below is mine:

@ComponentScan("boot.web,boot.service,boot.repository,boot.app")

and my directory structure is follows:
src/main/
-----boot.app
-----------App.java
-----boot.domain
-----boot.repository
-----boot.service
-----boot.web
App.java is my startup class.

Comment: I have just edit my post ( again .. ) i had an picture to see my architecture, but i don't really well understand the componentScan ...

Comment: @ComponentScan("controllers") is not contain the service and repository,so you must modify it to @ComponentScan("controllers,services,repository,model")
ComponentScan is used for scanning the bean class while load the spring container.If you not configure the componentscan with the path of service and  repository,the class depend them(such as controller) will load failure.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same UnsatisfiedDependencyException and NoSuchBeanDefinitionException, so I checked that I had my `@Service` annotation on top of my service class, my `@Repository` on top of my JPA repository class, and that my Main class had `@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.first.package.*", "com.second.package.*" })` to scan the package where my repository is.

Then I noticed that 2 repositories had the same class name! One was in the first package, and the other was in the second package! So Spring loaded just one and not the second one.
I renamed the second repository and it worked! This could be also done using Qualifiers.